# Display user control in active workbook

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, user-controls, ribbon, excel-2019

I have a VSTO Excel Add-in project. I have a ribbon called "ManageTaskPaneRibbon" and on the ribbon I have a toggle button called "toggleButton1" which opens a User Control called "TaskPaneControl". When I run the addin and click on the button, the custom pane appears correctly in "Book1".

[Book1 opens pane correctly from ribbon toggle button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6IuPR.png)

But when I click on New Workbook, the ribbon in the new workbook "Book2" opens with the toggle button already clicked, like in "Book1".

[Book1 panel closes, Book2 toggle button unchecks, Book1 toggle button remains checked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oERFz.png)

When I click on the toggle button in "Book2" the pane in "Book1" disappears, the toggle button in "Book2" is now unchecked but the togglebutton in "Book1" remains checked.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k0J9Z.png)

I based my test on this walkthrough...

[Microsoft walkthrough example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-synchronizing-a-custom-task-pane-with-a-ribbon-button?view=vs-2019)

In ThisAddIn, I delcared an instance of TaskPaneControl...

```html
private TaskPaneControl taskPaneControl1;
private Microsoft.Office.Tools.CustomTaskPane taskPaneValue;
```

In ThisAddIn_Startup I added the TaskPaneControl to CustomTaskPanes field...

```html
  taskPaneControl1 = new TaskPaneControl();
  taskPaneValue = this.CustomTaskPanes.Add(taskPaneControl1, "MyCustomTaskPane");
  taskPaneValue.VisibleChanged += new EventHandler(taskPaneValue_VisibleChanged);
```

And in the toggle button click I added the code to display the pane...

```html
            Globals.ThisAddIn.TaskPane.Visible = ((RibbonToggleButton)sender).Checked;
            Globals.ThisAddIn.TaskPane.DockPosition = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoCTPDockPosition.msoCTPDockPositionLeft;
            Globals.ThisAddIn.TaskPane.Width = 250;
```

I'm not sure whether I need to load a new instance of the ribbon when a new file is opened or if I need to create a new instance of the panel. Of course I am not sure how to do either. Can anyone help me figure this out?

Thanks
T

Answer (score 0):

If your source was `https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-add-a-custom-task-pane-to-an-application`, then:

Keep in mind that the equivalent of "this" in C# is the same as "Me" in vb.net.

it might be causing you that no other interop is being activated other that the 1st instance.

Comment: Please avoid using links since they may die at some point. Copy and paste relevant text from the link location.